# How to include existing div from header to be part of Menu in mobile using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a site, where I have Login div as part of header in Desktop view. Where as the same div has to be appear in Mobile menu along with existing menu items as shown below:

[image]

[image]

So, how to implement this as part of mobile menu item (Without using 2 Divs for hide/show) using Bootstrap?

Comment: you can use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `navbar` class for your header. And then bootstrap will automatically behave that way. Otherwise you should use the [media query](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).
Or you could use the `visible-xs`, `visible-sm`, etc. bootstrap classes (with mulitple div's), to handle what is viewed on which device.

Answer (score 0):

first of all this is no javascript / jquery question. 
What you wannt to do is explained [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

> See how aspects of the Bootstrap grid system work across multiple devices with a handy table.

bootstrap itself does the job just read that doc

Answer (score 0):

I Think You Have Too Use `.col-md` class from bootstrap.

Give Class OF menu div as `col-md-4` and in login and content div has `col-md-8`.

For Example,

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="menu col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="login col-md-8"></div>
</div>
```

Just Like This...
If You Are Don't familiar with Bootstrap. Then First Read Out The Documentation That Will Suggested By **Burak Topal** . So You are understand that what this class will actually do.

Might This Will Helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this without using media queries. We need to place both top and left navbars inside ".navbar-collapse" class.
I have used a custom class "navbar-fixed-left" to make the left navbar.

```
.navbar-fixed-left {      
    margin-top: 47px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 140px;      
    position: fixed;      
    border-radius: 0;      
    height: 100%;    
}           

.navbar-fixed-left .navbar-nav > li {      
    float: none;  /* Cancel default li float: left */
    width: 139px;    
} 

.navbar-fixed-left + .container {      
        padding-left: 160px;
}

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
                  </form>

    <div class="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-left">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>




<div class="container">
  <h3>Content goes here...</h3>

</div>
```